# Why is a WindowBuilder event not getting called?

Tags: java, dialog, windowbuilder

I created a Java app in WindowBuilder for Eclipse. I built a menu and on one of the menu items I added the mouseclicked event.

```
JMenuItem mitemAbout = new JMenuItem("About");
    mitemAbout.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            JOptionPane.showInternalMessageDialog( form, "Message", "title", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

        }
    });
    mitemHelp.add(mitemAbout);
```

I put a breakpoint on the JOptionPane line and when I click on the menu item in debug mode it doesn't even get to it.
Am I completely missing a step here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although `JMenuItem` components offer the `addMouseListener` method (inherited from `java.awt.Component`) `MouseEvents` are only processed for the `MenuElements` own functional use, i.e. any external `MouseEvents` will have no effect.

For `JMenuItem` components, use an `ActionListener` rather than a `MouseListener` to listen for user events:

```
mitemAbout.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      ...               
}
});
```

or use:

```
mitemAbout.setAction(myAction);
```